# How to show that $I(V(f))=\left\langle f\right\rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered several similar questions in Ideal, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox et al.

I showed that $I(V(xyz))=\left\langle xyz\right\rangle$ by arguing that if $f$ vanishes whenever $x=0$, then $f=xf_1$ for some $f_1\in \mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$ and similarly for $y,z$. So $f$ has to be $xyz\cdot g$, hence in $\left\langle xyz\right\rangle$.

Now I am trying to do this question:

> Show that $I(V((x+y+z)(x+y-z)(x-y+z)(x-y-z)))=\left\langle (x+y+z)(x+y-z)(x-y+z)(x-y-z)\right\rangle$

I have two questions:

1. Can I just say since $f$ vanishes whenever $x+y+z=0$, so $f=(x+y+z)f_1$ and so on?
2. I know I cannot use this method to show it when the ideal contains more functions. So is this the general method for the single function case to show  $I(V(f))=\left\langle f\right\rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}[x,y,z]$>?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For 2 above, what happens if $f=x^2+1$? So, it clearly depends on whether you think of $V(f)$ as real points or prime (or maximal) ideals of the ring.

Comment: @Mohan: Right. I've been thinking that. It cannot be the general method. But it should work when the factors are linear like above.

Comment: Your profile says you love teaching and you love math. What a beautiful declaration, dear Kitty !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Thank you for your warm words! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion 1. at the end of your question is true but 2. is false:
For example if $f=x^2+y^2+z^2$ then $$I(V(f))=I(\{(0,0,0)\})=\langle x,y,z \rangle \supsetneq \langle f \rangle=\langle x^2+y^2+z^2  \rangle $$

To prove 1. change coordinates and assume $f=x$.
Then write $f=a(y,z)+b(y,z)x+c(y,z)x^2+\dots $ and conclude.